# Multiple scales, same underlying feature, terminology

Tags: terminology, scales, latent-variable

Disclaimer: I'm a computer scientist and only a wannabe statistician, this question might therefore be naive, please indulge me.

I am working on a model using data measuring the same real world feature on different scales. Assume for instance that I model temperature but one set of data has the target value in Farenheit and another set has the target value in Celsius. Now assume that there is no a priori formula for conversion between these scales (perhaps one is "too warm", "just right", "too cold" and the other is "hot", "warm", "lukewarm", "cool", "chilly", "cold") and that the model needs to handle both scales at the same time (as a latent variable in my approach, but that is not the issue).

My problem is rather one of terminology, what do I call this situation with multiple overlapping scales on the same variable? I first thought of "multiscale", but that has more to do with non-overlapping scales, such as including both sub-atomic and molecular components into a larger model. I thought that perhaps "heteroscale" might be reasonable but perhaps there is an established term out there?

Comment: Perhaps "hidden units" data? (Aside: When hearing a complex query, I sometimes jokingly answer "the answer is definitely 2, but I cannot tell you the units!")

Comment: Heh, I will remember that one :)

Answer (score 1):

You might like the term "multimethod", which doesn't have much currency on its own, but appears in the term "multitrait-multimethod matrix". The way a psychometrician would describe your situation is that you have several measures (i.e., scales) of the same construct (i.e., underlying thing to be measured). "Multimeasure" would be a reasonable choice of neologism.